# Eclipse>WST>JSDT Javascript Refactoring Renaming variables working half of the time

Tags: javascript, eclipse, refactoring, rename, jsdt

In `Eclipse` (I am running 3.8.0 @ Linux (Mint 14 (Ubuntu (Debian))) at the moment), renaming variables using `Refactor` is an option that seems randomly available. For some code it's there, and for other code it's not.

I tried to see a pattern why some `var` declarations are up for renaming and others are not, but I haven't found it yet.

Why does refactor->rename not work for some code? How can I make this work?

**You can see by the highlighted references that Eclipse is very aware of what should be refactored,** so I don't understand what the problem is.

No problem:
[image]

Problem:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can always use `Ctrl + 2 + R` (Press R after appearing a small dropdown) to refactor the variable... [ Got it by chance ].

**Update**

working on Eclipse Neon... can't say about other older version. because it is the latest stable version at the time I am writing the answer.

**Update 3-May-2017**

one drawback is that it replaces all occurrences of that variable in the file.
special care is required.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that renaming is not available, when the project is not a JS project or if I open it with the non-default JS editor. (Spket JS Editor in my case.)

So try this:

- Make sure in your .project file jsNature is set.

E.g. (In my case I have JS code inside a Java project):

```
<natures>
    <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    <nature>org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature</nature>
</natures>
```

- Right click file -> Open with -> JavaScript Editor

Works for my using Eclipse Kepler.

Comment: Sometimes Eclipse tells me "refactoring cannot be performed, since its input variable does not exist". --> Just click OK, then CTRL+Z (undo) until all instances of the variable are renamed.

Answer (score 0):

I can rename the local variable under Aptana Studio 3.0 (Eclipse based) with the JSDT "JavaScript Editor" and in the screenshot shown JS function: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnkJj.jpg

Comment: This doesn't really address the OP's problem. You may be able to do this, but he's asking why he can't. Do you know of a difference between your system and his?

Comment: Thanks for the efford, but like _Mike W_ said, this doesn't really give me a clue. I am wondering if it makes a difference whether you're running Aptana as stand-alone software or as an Eclipse plugin?