# Eclipse JSDT autocomplete not working

Tags: javascript, eclipse, jsdt, eclipse-jsdt

I've done research and see this is a recognized issue. I guess my question will be: Is there a solution in Eclipse Mars or in Neon? Another plugin for JavaScript Content Assist?

I'm running Eclipse Mars and have a project with Java and JavaScript (uses ScriptEngineManager). JavaDoc/AutoComplete is working in Java but not in JS files. It Was working but then just stopped. I've restarted, rebooted, refreshed, rebuilt. No joy. The error reported is :

`An exception occurred while getting the JSDoc. See log for details.
(in the log: ) file.js [in [in ...Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core\libraries\system.js]] does not exist`

I deleted and re-defined the workspace. No joy. Mouseover the keyword **Array** and it does show system.jsArray with ECMA info. But mouseover **String** and it shows `src/docs/jsString`. "src/docs" is a path in my project.

I'm thinking it's just looking in the wrong place for the docs but I don't know where to set that. I've read that there is a bug where auto complete only works within a file. This seems to be consistent where it's still looking within the current file for the definition of everything.

I can get String to refer back to system.jsString if I add an invalid function. But if I fix the function it goes back to looking in my src/docs. Go figure.

Maybe the project structure is wrong (this is FOSS I got from Github). In the root of the project there are src/foo folders with packages and .java source, a reference to the JRE System Library, a couple .jars, and another src folder with src/docs/java with .java files and src/docs/js with .js files. Do I need to change the folder type of src or do something else to it so that it's recognized as a code folder? Right now it's in the project explorer with a common "folder" icon, not like one of the package source folders.

Do I need Neon? Do I need another IDE?
[This suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25377826/190955) to update the .project  didn't help.
I'm going to try the package "Eclipse IDE for JavaScript and Web Developers" but I dont know if that will help with this Java/JS hybrid project. I'm also going to try Atom.

Thanks.